# how to use a constant as a range index

Tags: vba, range, constants, variable-assignment

I want to use this construct

```
Option Explicit

Public Const CellLocation As String = "5, 7"

... .

data = range1(CellLocation ).Value
```

My code works for
    data = range1( 5, 7 ).Value

but not for
    data = range1( CellLocation ).Value

How can I specify the cell location as a constant

Comment: I am assuming that you are wanting to set row 5, column 7 as a constant. If this is the case, have you tried assigning "G5" as the value of CellLocation?

Comment: Or define a variable for row and for column and reference as ' = range1(lRow, lCol).Value' or define as 'Range' then populate & reference

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but can't you use "offset" here.

```
Set CellLocation = Cells(5,7)
```